# How to get state codes from JS in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript

I need to add a function which will be check order *state* in JS for show/hide content in rows in Orders (Admin Panel).

In php I can use something like Order:STATE_COMPLETE, but in JS I don't know how to get this.

Comment: Sorry,donot understood your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly from JS. The JS framework of Magento 2 does not have any knowledge of database information, unless you toss the information to your JS or template. What you could do it collect the data in PHP, and add it to your block so you can use it in your template. Or you could do an Ajax call to your server when you need the data.

Comment: Ok, I have used variables: var STATE_CANCELED = 'canceled';